# When decrypting an encrypted string in c#, only the first character is returned

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption

I have an encryption algorithm and decryption algorithm used for a login page. When encrypting, everything seems fine and seems to encrypt everything as expected, but when the encrypted password is put back through my decryption algorithm, only the first character is returned.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIHg5.png)

Here is the code:

```
public string encrypt(string key, string data)
        {
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                encryptor.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                encryptor.IV = iv;
                encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();

                    }
                    data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }


            }
            return data;
        }

        public static string decryptData(string key, string data)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            byte[] clearBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

            using (Aes decrpytor = Aes.Create())
            {
                decrpytor.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                decrpytor.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = decrpytor.CreateDecryptor(decrpytor.Key, decrpytor.IV);
                decrpytor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(clearBytes))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream((Stream)ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader((Stream)cs))
                        {
                        
                            return sr.ReadToEnd();
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var key = "b14ca5898a4e4133bbce2ea2315a1916";
            var str = passWord.Text;
            var encryptedPassword = encrypt(key, str);
            var decrpted = decryptData(key, encryptedPassword);
            passwordTest.Text = encryptedPassword;
            decryptedtest.Text = decrpted;

        }
```

the last 2 lines are purely for testing to see what they output.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You encrypt as unicode but decrypt as utf8 (the default of StreamReader). Beyond that i think that could work. By the way for a password encryption seems wrong normally you want to just hash it.

Comment: You are badly off-course; [passwords need to be hashed, not encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45062/). Encrypted passwords can be recovered; you don't want that. Why are you making passwords for a WinForm app any way? Windows already comes with a perfectly good sign-in mechanism, so you already know who is running your app.

Comment: Maybe he is doing password manager ...

Comment: ^^ are you, Charlie?

Comment: I am encrypting the passwords to be put into a database, the decrypting them later on the backend to check if the details are correct when logging in. If hashing is best used for this situation I shall change it to that.

Comment: His first sentence says “used for a login page.” Not a password manager. The screenshot is of a login dialog with password in cleartext. Login. Page.

Comment: @CharlieGale Yes do that

Comment: It was mainly to get decrypting and encrypting in there for my college "project". But if hashing is better practice im sure that would be fine

Comment: Use the `CryptoStream.Read()` method to read to a buffer. This method returns the bytes read. Use this value to then read from the buffer that number of bytes, convert with `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` (e.g., `return Encoding.Unicode.GetString([Buffer], 0, [Count]);`)  -- Don't need to cast to Stream what is already a Stream -- You can use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` or `SHA256` to hash the password. Or maybe use a dedicated library

Comment: *"encrypting the passwords to be put into a database"* - Never do this. This is how security breaches result in leaked passwords. If they can be decrypted, you're done.

Comment: If you just need to show encryption _somewhere_ in your project, then better _not_ do it on the passwords.

Comment: Doing something for "research" is always a good excuse. Personally I'd always build in some methods to verify the correctness of the master key / password and add some kind of (HMAC) authentication tag to make sure that the integrity of the DB can be maintained. It would also fend off padding / plaintext oracles although that might be less of a worry if the data remains "at rest" (there is no service and therefore oracle that performs the decryption). You should use a Password Based Key Derivation Function such as PBKDF2 to get a key from a master password.

Comment: **Security warning**: do NOT use the above code in production as it is highly **INSECURE**. The code is using static IV (initvector) [iv = new byte[16] is giving 16 bytes of x00]. Better use a random generated IV and prepend it to the ciphertext (do not need to be "secured") so that the decryption can be done, thanks.